# Sharing Data between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 Store App

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I am about to begin a fairly simple application, but I want to make sure I structure the backend of the application correctly because I plan to expand on it greatly in the future. Here's my question:

I am creating both a Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 Store application. In this case, it is a unit conversion application where the user is given the ability to define custom unit conversion units. I would like to allow the user to essentially sync those custom units between the two platforms so that they don't need to define them multiple times.

What backend approach should I take?

XML storage coupled with SkyDrive, Azure, a local database that syncs over USB....There are a lot of options, and I'm not sure which way is preferred in the scenario I described above. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As for actual data sharing I would suggest using Azure, which is a bit more reliable and also transparent for the user (as opposed to a local db syncing over USB) and cleaner than XML-files in SkyDrive (the user doesn't need to see these files anyway).

As for code sharing you could use two techniques:

- Portable Class Libraries
- Linked Files

I have recently written two articles on this:

http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/03/27/portable-class-libraries-or-source-code-sharing/

http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/02/24/patterns-for-sharing-code-in-windows-phone-and-windows-8-applications/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually have to be Azure, if you are shooting for lower price range. You can also choose a webhosting and use build a WebAPI service, which will help you sync your data and put them on all devices. Of course, Azure is being preferred as the ultimate solution, because it offers much more features.

Comment: note that Azure covers a lot of territory from options that can be free forever (Web Sites) to enterprise features with enterprise pricetags.  Many mobile apps can use [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) with an outlay of maybe $5-10 per month depending on load, space needs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have used windows 8 [roaming data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx) support for one app. In my case, data is simply the history of user operations in the app and data size is < 1k. windows 8 roaming data support can support up to 100k of data as per documentation and is a good start for w8 apps with very low investment. it covers for all w8 devices. it is certainly good for simple key/value pair kind of data for user.

Now the caveats - currently, it does not support [windows phone](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1a661018-6506-40c5-8fdb-5ed4b95a3d36) roaming currently. It is a [feature ask](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/3681562-roaming-application-data) for phone 8 - it can be voted up. Finally, this will not roam to android and other mobile devices.

Another way to think about it - when do you need to build it?

If it is simply per user data storage - backend need not come in place in first release. You can start with w8 roaming data support and in future release x, it can be moved from windows 8 roaming data to skydrive or your web api or azure. what I mean to say, it need not be built affront.

If the backend is going to allow sharing of data between users or experience over aggregated data from multiple users - then, it is all together different problem. in that case, roaming data is not a solution. a backend web api or service is must.

HTH.

Other references: [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx) for windows 8 roaming data.